# Express API post request works locally but failed on Heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, heroku, mongoose

so I have an express API. Post request sent to it works locally, but when I deployed it to Heroku, it failed when I tested with Postman. Here I will show you what I get from `heroku logs` and my server, route code:

```
## Heroku logs
 
2020-06-28T17:00:26.000169+00:00 app[api]: Release v4 created by user 
2020-06-28T17:00:26.165056+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-06-28T17:00:27.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-06-28T17:00:28.324211+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-06-28T17:00:30.918283+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-06-28T17:00:30.918309+00:00 app[web.1]: > myapp@1.0.0 start /app
2020-06-28T17:00:30.918310+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2020-06-28T17:00:30.918310+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-06-28T17:00:32.474593+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-06-28T17:01:01.738558+00:00 app[web.1]: connect succesfully!
2020-06-28T17:01:31.772725+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=peaceful-sierra-47869.herokuapp.com request_id=223793a6-f77d-4a2b-83bf-0c73ab117775 fwd="75.71.7.56" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=12ms status=404 bytes=383 protocol=https
2020-06-28T17:01:54.442464+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/" host=peaceful-sierra-47869.herokuapp.com request_id=dea03d53-8229-49fc-88e0-0dc083afa904 fwd="75.71.7.56" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=35ms status=404 bytes=384 protocol=https
2020-06-28T17:02:07.616543+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/signup" host=peaceful-sierra-47869.herokuapp.com request_id=42fa1047-67da-4d40-a559-165a45ec6668 fwd="75.71.7.56" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=14ms status=422 bytes=425 protocol=https
2020-06-28T17:02:19.649813+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/signup" host=peaceful-sierra-47869.herokuapp.com request_id=8184a15b-928c-4cb3-8bb2-0793f8942bd3 fwd="75.71.7.56" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=422 bytes=429 protocol=https
2020-06-28T17:02:51.161097+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/signup" host=peaceful-sierra-47869.herokuapp.com request_id=2b65550d-1a68-499c-b65e-52a93727ba1c fwd="75.71.7.56" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7ms status=422 bytes=321 protocol=https
2020-06-28T17:03:02.233071+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/signup" host=peaceful-sierra-47869.herokuapp.com request_id=676d4fac-d641-4f6f-ac2c-0623ceb95c31 fwd="75.71.7.56" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2020-06-28T17:03:27.842943+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/signup" host=peaceful-sierra-47869.herokuapp.com request_id=e23ee5d6-6133-484b-83d1-d9aa8a8d805e fwd="75.71.7.56" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30003ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2020-06-28T17:38:31.314094+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2020-06-28T17:38:31.316222+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2020-06-28T17:38:32.632834+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2020-06-28T17:38:32.800439+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2020-06-28T18:41:53.590065+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2020-06-28T18:41:53.633857+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2020-06-28T18:41:56.534301+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-06-28T18:41:59.583503+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-06-28T18:41:59.583531+00:00 app[web.1]: > myapp@1.0.0 start /app
2020-06-28T18:41:59.583531+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2020-06-28T18:41:59.583531+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-06-28T18:42:00.831129+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-06-28T18:42:15.614809+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=peaceful-sierra-47869.herokuapp.com request_id=106c03a3-bb7b-4aa0-a5dc-6ff21fbf9dfc fwd="75.71.7.56" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=404 bytes=383 protocol=https
2020-06-28T18:42:18.614798+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=peaceful-sierra-47869.herokuapp.com request_id=84b3c61c-a58c-4040-b3fd-af97ec6a28ea fwd="75.71.7.56" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=383 protocol=https
2020-06-28T18:42:30.472774+00:00 app[web.1]: connect succesfully!
2020-06-28T18:42:31.688047+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/signup" host=peaceful-sierra-47869.herokuapp.com request_id=35de2b28-ac52-4247-a52e-87206f35eb37 fwd="75.71.7.56" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2020-06-28T18:45:15.640333+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=peaceful-sierra-47869.herokuapp.com request_id=2ce30c29-d330-4c7a-a24d-82c0016b22fa fwd="75.71.7.56" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=383 protocol=https
2020-06-28T18:45:58.206548+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/signup" host=peaceful-sierra-47869.herokuapp.com request_id=a57c93f5-cf60-4c28-b99f-9e924cbf6270 fwd="75.71.7.56" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2020-06-28T18:51:44.193312+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/signup" host=peaceful-sierra-47869.herokuapp.com request_id=fec8c8a1-d7c5-4393-8852-e36771cf1dfc fwd="75.71.7.56" dyno=web.1 connect=5ms service=30006ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2020-06-28T19:20:18.334810+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2020-06-28T19:20:18.337241+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2020-06-28T19:20:19.565141+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2020-06-28T19:20:19.664454+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2020-06-28T21:05:43.391044+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2020-06-28T21:05:43.407486+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2020-06-28T21:05:46.540194+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-06-28T21:05:49.717362+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-06-28T21:05:49.717420+00:00 app[web.1]: > myapp@1.0.0 start /app
2020-06-28T21:05:49.717426+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2020-06-28T21:05:51.082642+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-06-28T21:05:52.504484+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/users/1" host=peaceful-sierra-47869.herokuapp.com request_id=0f6e0493-a67d-4597-979f-f3c3a3091465 fwd="75.71.7.56" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=48ms status=200 bytes=246 protocol=https
2020-06-28T21:06:20.679758+00:00 app[web.1]: connect succesfully!
2020-06-28T21:07:34.667678+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/signup" host=peaceful-sierra-47869.herokuapp.com request_id=fb9ceb56-1991-483a-be45-95d339ad3cec fwd="75.71.7.56" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2020-06-28T21:08:41.256696+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/signup" host=peaceful-sierra-47869.herokuapp.com request_id=9fc27994-88bb-43c8-a9ef-b5e2aa20c6bf fwd="75.71.7.56" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2020-06-28T21:16:20.848755+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/signup" host=peaceful-sierra-47869.herokuapp.com request_id=b0ac5b4c-9349-488a-8446-31dc01ed00fb fwd="75.71.7.56" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=http
2020-06-28T21:16:31.106986+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/signup" host=peaceful-sierra-47869.herokuapp.com request_id=b0ac31ae-4cb6-42b5-a99f-cc48564783a1 fwd="75.71.7.56" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30002ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2020-06-28T21:22:32.020268+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/signup" host=peaceful-sierra-47869.herokuapp.com request_id=206ab63d-718a-43ea-899a-0200f4444106 fwd="75.71.7.56" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

```
## server.js
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = express();
const PORT = 5000;
const routes = require('./routes');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(async (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.headers && req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[0]==='JWT') {
    token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    jwt.verify(token, 'secret', (err, decoded) => {
      err? res.json(err.message) : req.user = decoded;
      next();
    } );
  } else {
    req.user = undefined;
    next();
  }
});

app.use('/', routes);

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/my_important_dates', {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,
}, ()=>{
  console.log('connect succesfully!');
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || PORT);
```

```
## user routes
const express = require('express');
const eventRoutes = require('./event_routes');
// eslint-disable-next-line new-cap
const router = express.Router();
const validateUser = require('../validator');
const {getUser, updateUser, loginRequired, rightUser} = require('../controllers/usersController');

router.use(loginRequired);

router.route('/:id')
    .get(getUser)
    .put(rightUser, validateUser, updateUser);// You have to be the right user to change the user


router.use('/:id/events', eventRoutes);

module.exports = router;
```

```
## userController.js
const User = require('../models/user');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const signUp = (req, res) => {
  User.init()
      .then( async ()=>{
        const user = new User(req.body);
        user.hashPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 10);
        const result = await user.save();
        res.json(result);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        res.json(err);
      });
};

module.exports = {getUser, signUp, updateUser, login, loginRequired, rightUser};
```

Since I got the error saying that `request timeout`, so I am guessing if it has to do with MongoDB database hanging?
Also, one thing that is strange, when I use wrong data to sign up, I did get error messages back, but when I use good data to request, the response is hanging there

But BTW whoever wants to restore the problem, here is the link: https://peaceful-sierra-47869.herokuapp.com/signup and you can make a post request to it with this:

```
"name": "aaa123",
"email": "l123@123.com",
"password": "pas8889"
}
```

**Update: so I "fix" the problem by simply changing the MongoDB connect URL from localhost to MongoDB atlas URL. I don't know why the previous MongoDB URL doesn't work. So I didn't close the question. Please leave your answer if you know, but one thing to mention is that, if you use the API link, it will work now, but just bc I use MongoDB Atlas.**

Thank you!

Comment: I just tested the endpoint via postman and it's working fine. I'm guessing you fixed whatever the problem was. I suggest you either post the fix you applied or close this question so as to avoid others wasting their effort trying to answer a question that is already resolved.

Comment: @Tunmee Sorry, I did fix it but by transferring to MongoDB atlas. So I didn't really "fix" the problem yet, that's why I want to wait for answers still. But I will put it in the original post so people know that it is fixed by barely changing to atlas. Idk why only MongoDB doesn't work after I deployed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A connection URI in this format `mongodb://localhost**` refers to a database running locally on the server. - [Source](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#database-server-running-locally).

Unless you've installed MongoDB on your Heroku server(which I believe you did not), you won’t be able to connect to a MongoDB instance running locally on the server. This explains why the request was timing out when a DB operation is expected to happen and why changing the connection URI to reference a MongoDB Atlas instance fixed the problem.